# Pause loading script and resume after load element of DOM

Tags: javascript, jira

I need the js script to stop and wait until a certain element appears on the page.
Can this be done with promises?
The fact is that the portal on which the script is used dynamically loads pages without going to the URL, and the necessary part of the script is to be executed on a specific page

Comment: Could you give a more detailed description of the context please ? Some code, things you tried etc, something understandable and reproducible from the outside :).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I hope I explained clearly

Comment: @Peterrabbit There is a portal for users - JSD. The user needs to click on the "Edit interview date" button so that the editing window appears. This button is located in the "My Requests" section. In order for the user to get to this page, he needs to go to the main page and go to the "My requests" section. This mechanism has been implemented and is working. BUT The fact is that the site is dynamically loaded. And when you go to the next section, it does not load another page, but works "seamlessly" (without reloading). The script works if you do a reboot in the "My Requests" section

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stoping execution, you can move the code into into its own function and execute only after the element appears in DOM.

```
var check = setInterval("checkElem", 200);

function checkClear() {
  clearInterval(check);
}

function checkElem() {
  const el1 = document.getElementById("element1");

  if (el1 !== null) {
    console.log("executing");
    yourFunction();
    checkClear();
  } else {
    console.log("element does NOT exist");
  }
}

function yourFunction() {
  //your executable code
  return "some-value";
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't handle the detection of the element being appended to the DOM after a while.

Comment: Thanks, thats right. Modified the code a bit to have setInterval check for the DOM element periodically.